# How to add a navigation to another screen in a list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have made a dart file where I will pull static data and call them in another dart file. Those data need a navigation to another screen but I cannot find a way to add the navigation.
Here is the list without path:

````
  "Delivery",
  "Transfer",
  "Consumption",
  "Adjustment",
];```

and the result I want to achieve is something like this:

    ```List tasks = [
    
    {'label': 'Delivery',
     'path': ' Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/deliveryScreen');'
    },
      {'label': 'Transfer',
        'path': ' Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/transferScreen');'
      },
    
    ];```

Is there a way of doing it? Cheers
````

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You could just add the name of the path to the corresponding page widget you want to navigate to, like:

```
List tasks = [
  { 'label': 'Delivery', 'path': '/deliveryScreen' },
  { 'label': 'Transfer', 'path': '/transferScreen' }
];
```

Each one of them will correspond to your routes (if you're doing it like this on your **MaterialApp** routes):

```
...
routes: {
  '/deliveryScreen': (context) => const DeliveryScreen(),
  '/transferScreen': (context) => const TransferScreen()
}
...
```

Then is all a matter of you accessing that **tasks** lists wherever you'll be rendering the navigation strategy you need (i.e. you want to do a *Row** of **TextButton** widgets, as in):

```
Row(
  children: List.generate(tasks.length, (index) {
     var task = tasks[index];

     return TextButton(
       onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(task['path']));
       },
       child: Text(task['label'])
     );
  })
)
```